# Intellij IDEA не открывается

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA вообще не запускается: нажав на ярлык, ничего не происходи. Никаких сообщений или ошибок нет, просто ничего, совершенно ничего не происходит. Jdk стоит, JAVA_HOME прописан, все как положено. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, просто удалил и поставил заново. Прошу закрыть

Comment: Не просите закрыть. Если вопрос хороший - он поможет другим. Если плохой - будет закрыт. Если хотите удалить - это в ваших силах.

Comment: Если у кого возникнет, посмотрите свойство ярлыка, прописан-ли там рабочий каталог. Было такое уже и в виндовс и в линукс.